# jasperreport JRDataSource

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

While working on report for some client, guys and me, we've succeeded to define(Java), populate(from Hibernate v3.x) and 'feed' custom data source (in pseudo raw SQL something like:

```
select t1.c1,t2.c2,t3.c3 ... join-join-join ...
```

)

to

```
JasperFillManager(API v3.6.7):
ds = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fillReport(java.lang.String sourceFileName,      
    java.util.Map params, JRDataSource myCustomDataSource);
```

1. Now the BIG issue comes when we trying with `iReport (v4.0.2)` to populate this custom data source into report(either sub-report).
   We've tried to pass it as parameter, as single data source to `fillReport()` - nAdA. Help please.
2. Now at all, conceptualy or by example, how to pass number if different custom data sources into sub-reports. Example could be very helpful.

Appreciate the help,
--vs